# Компиляция через командную строку в С#

Tags: c#

Как указать путь в среде переменного окружения, чтобы можно было компилировать через командную строку С#-код. У меня уже стоит Visual Studio 2008 экспресс. Хотелось бы через командную строку компилировать научиться.

Comment: «Переменная среда» =).

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужен `csc.exe`.

Проблема в том, что этот файл обычно запрятан в недрах папки Windows (например, у меня он нашёлся в `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`). Так что лучше воспользуйтесь [`VSVARS32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1700bbwd.aspx).

[Command-line Building With csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Ещё компилятор C# имеет API, доступный в .NET Framework. Используется примерно так:

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Resources;

public void Compile(string[] resourceFiles, string[] references, string outputFileName)
{
  var compiledResources = new List<string>();
  foreach (string resourceFile in resourceFiles)
  {
    string resourceRoot = new FileInfo(outputFileName).Directory.FullName;
    using (ResXResourceReader reader = new ResXResourceReader(resourceFile))
    {
      string outResPath = resourceRoot + "\\"
        + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(resourceFile) + ".resources";
      using (ResourceWriter rw = new ResourceWriter(outResPath))
      {
        IDictionaryEnumerator ren = reader.GetEnumerator();
        while (ren.MoveNext())
        {
          rw.AddResource(ren.Key.ToString(), ren.Value.ToString());
        }
        compiledResources.Add(outResPath);
      }
    }
  }

  CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
  CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters(references.ToArray(), outputFileName);
  parameters.EmbeddedResources.AddRange(compiledResources.ToArray());
  CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, sourceCodes);

  foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
  {
    //speakOut(string.Format("Line:{0:d},Error:{1}\n", error.Line, error.ErrorText));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

“Мой компьютер” - свойства. Windows XP - "дополнительно", Windows Vista/7 -  "Дополнительные параметры системы". Вкладка "Дополнительно" - "Переменные среды..."
Далее в "Системные переменные" ищем переменную Path. В конце дописываем через точку с запятой путь к компилятору (например C:WindowsMicrosoft.NETFrameworkv4.0.30319)
Другой способ найти "переменные среды" - если Windows 7 - Пуск - в строке поиска "переменные среды"

Comment: Можно просто писать полный путь к csc в командной строке - прописывание в path не требуется. Хотя, если часто приходится так компилировать, это может быть удобно.

Answer (score 0):

Компилировать проект с кодом можно при помощи msbuild (не входит в клиентский профиль 4.0, но входит во все остальные), отдельными файлами - при помощи csc (он есть везде) - ищи их в папке с .net framework'ом.

http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=44609 - bat-файл для компиляции VB.NET (при помощи vbc), C# делается аналогично.